# How to show error message after textbox without overflow row

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add error message for textbox. I am trying to show it below textbox. When the error message is showing grid row height should increase. Check out the following image so you will get the idea.

[image: Error message is overflow outside row of grid]

I am attaching the code of leftside (Textbox part) code and my style code.

**View.xaml**

```
<!-- Other Code -->
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{StaticResource m-20}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border" >
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,5,5,5" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="Reg. No." Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=currentTrust.RegNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" MaxLength="{Binding Path=currentTrust.RegNo.MaxLength}" InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="en-IN"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="Trust" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=currentTrust.TrustName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="Address" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=currentTrust.Address, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,IsAsync=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Content="Contact No" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=currentTrust.ContactNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,IsAsync=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource AccentButton}" Content="{Binding Path=ButtonActionText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,IsAsync=True}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding AddTrust}" />
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Cancel"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding CancelTrust}" Margin="{StaticResource ml-5}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
<!-- Other Code -->
```

**style.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource p-5}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="DarkRed" Margin="0 0 0 5">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="placeholder" />
                    </Border>
                    <Label Content="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="Red"
                        FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I tried wrap panel, controltemplate etc. But it doesn't impact.

Comment: I think you mean "I am attaching the code of *right side* (Textbox part)."

Comment: @NaitikKundalia: The validation `Label` is displayed in the adorner layer.  If you want the height of the row to increase, you need to increase it yourself.